# Google Analytics: Report delayed conversion?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have a site that tracks conversions through Google Analytics for redirects to an affiliate.  However, not all redirected visitors convert to a sale after they leave our site.  Our affiliate reports back to us weekly on who converted (and we can identify an individual user session from that report).  Is there a way to get that conversion data back into Analytics?  We've got a great coding team, but I just need to point them in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Good question Jeff.  If you don't mind the accuracy of the timing being off, your team could certainly just step through your site and intentionally trip the conversions.

Other than that, you may look into using a custom solution to bulk import that data using this type of API: [Google Analytics for Mobile Websites](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/mobileWebsites.html)

This Google Analytic server-side solution supports PERL, ASP.NET, JSP, and PHP.  If you're looking for a repeatable process for batch importing GA data, this maybe a viable solution for you.

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend manually 'tripping' the conversions.

There is no easy way to get the data back into Analytics. And it would depend on your reporting requirements (time lines, etc)

One way to approach this is to set a custom variable that is scoped to a visitor that would identify the visitor in an anonymous way (not personally identifiable manner, beware the  privacy policy).

http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/05/05/merging-google-analytics-with-your-data-warehouse/

So when a visitor comes to the site, a custom variable would get set. This variable acts as a key to associate behavior on the site and the affiliates. Once you receive the data about which visitors converted from your affiliates associated to the non-personally-identifiable ID, you can use this to have code fire some conversion events once it recognizes on a separate visit that a visitor with certain custom variables set using the `_getVisitorCustomVar()`

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The piece of this that I'm stumbling on is (to quote you) "have code fire some conversion events once it recognizes on a separate visit..."  Once a visitor converts, we generally never see them again.  I'm not overly concerned with timing reporting, but I can tell you that we would need to set those conversion events about 2 weeks after they happened in most cases.